# jenkins build git checkout not working as per branch selection by git-parameter 0.9.6 plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins 2.89.4 and git plugin 3.8 and git-parameter 0.9.6 while doing build git checkout should work be as per my selection criteria which i configure branch name using git-parameter plugin but at the time of build git checkout working as per mention in git-plugin and not by git-parameter plugin.

Comment: can you share how you are using these plugins

Comment: In Build config i am using git-parameter type is branch in project is parameterized and at the time of build it will give me list of branches with the name for selection of branch for use to build the code.

Answer (score 0):

Git-Parameter plugin not required in this solution

[image]

Then in Source Code Management section update Branches to build to use string parameter defined 
[image]

This will allow jenkins job to use default branch as master and for manual builds it will ask you to enter branch details (FYI: by default it's set to master)

[image]